# samsung android usb device disconnect reconnect constantly windows 7

Tags: android, windows, usb, driver, mtu

When I connect samsung tab s2 to pc windows 7, initially windows does not recognize usb device, or MTU driver failed install, many error.

I uninstall all other usb driver, still has problem.

samsung android usb driver, unknow device, usb device disconnect constantly

MTU usb driver, not installed properly.

not sure what is the cause.

=============================================

Updated:

The problem solved by Buy a non-samsung, non-OEM cable.

This this so bad, that samsung OEM cable is the reason of all trouble.

I end up spend $10 buy any brand(except Samsung) cable on amazon.

Comment: This is usually caused by your cable, try a new one :)

Comment: my samsung tab s2 and tab pro 8 can't connect to pc windows 7. device manager showing unknow device, device manger constantly refreshing. I try million way, find out Samsung OEM micro usb cable is the problem, I replace it with other brand from best buy, all problem fixed.

Comment: related for those struggling with disconnection of android after a delay: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/adb-constantly-disconnects-shows-device-offline/236909#236909

Answer (score 0):

samsung android usb driver, unknow device, usb device disconnect constantly

MTU usb driver, not installed properly.

Samsung OEM micro usb cable is the ultimate cause,  when you move or touch the cable around, it get disconnected, device manger constantly refreshing, constantly scan for hardware change.

Replace Samsung  OEM micro usb cable with any other brand will fix all problem.

==========================================================

For my HP Desktop.

1) repeat press F10 when power on, get into BIOS configure.

2) on top menu - advanced  - device option - USB 3.0 support (enable it), default is disabled.

3) sometime device manager refresh scan for hardware change, then unknow device,

this is because windows install driver from windows update, should disable it, should let windows install driver from samsung driver folder only,

Disable Searching Windows Update for Device Drivers

Click Start, right-click Computer, and then click Properties.
In the Tasks list, click Advanced System Settings.
On the System Properties dialog box, click the Hardware tab, and then click Windows Update Driver Settings.
Select Never check for drivers when I connect a device.
Click OK twice, and then close the System dialog box.

I believe this is the real cause for all trouble, such as MTU usb driver not installed properly, samsung android device not recognized by PC,  android usb device constantly disconnect and reconnect and failed to recognized. etc.....

---

if you use android simulator, must enable bios vt-x visualation technology from bios

bios - security - system security - visualation technology - enable.

Leeds VT enable.jpg

below are try may not be the cause.

=====================================================

try:

1) remove previously installed blue tooth usb device. (or SD card), they may be the problem.

2) remove google androic studio ( maybe problem )

3) unplug internet. ( I see samsung continuing removed add, remove add, not sure if computer keep removing hardware)

=========================

windows, device manager, 'scan for hardware change' constantly , android device disconnect constantly,

1. Scroll to the right and type 'Power Options' in the search field and click on it.
2. Click 'Change plan setting' on your chosen plan.
3. Click 'Change advanced power setting' on your chosen plan.
4. Find 'USB settings' and open.
5. Find 'USB selective suspend setting' and change it to disabled.

---

This fixed ALL my USB 3.0 issues. Not mentioned anywhere else!

Its a BIOS ISSUE. Hopefully your computer has this option.

Go into your BIOS and TURN OFF "Legacy USB Support".

If you want even more speed, (there is a catch), Switch from "quick remove" to Buffering. BUT YOU HAVE TO DISCONNECT THE DRIVE WITH THE REMOVE USB DEVICE OR POWER DOWN THE COMPUTER FIRST.

---

hey guys here is the fix if you are having trouble with your Windows 8.1 all USB devices keep disconnect / reconnect with power saving off ... this took me two days to try to figure out what the heck was going on so i luckily found the fix hope this saves you alot of time an you dont have to downgrade to windows 7 if you love windows 8.1 good because its not what virgin of windows you have it dosnt matter what OS your on its clearly your BIOS so i suppose many people having this problem has an ASUS motherboard so heres the fix

1. restart your computer an go into your BIOS Press F2 repeatedly or THE DEL Key for those who dont know how to go to BIOS

2.Go into Advanced mode in your BIOS by clicking F7 on keyboard

3.Go to Advanced Tab Scroll down to USB Configuration Scroll down to XHCI Mode yours Will probably be on Smart Auto or Auto so Disable it Completely an Save changes F10 an click yes an exit it will auto restart your computer an BOOM You have Fixed the Problem by simply reading this post Hope this helps guys

Answer (score 0):

my samsung tab s2 and tab pro 8 can't connect to pc windows 7. device manager showing unknow device, device manger constantly refreshing. I try million way, find out Samsung OEM micro usb cable is the problem, I replace it with other brand from best buy, all problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and I think it is related to actual motherboard driver (Windows 8, 10). I have several android devices and all of them are connecting/disconnecting every 1-2 sec.

Things I did:

- My BIOS doesn't have any configuration to switch USB 3.0 support
- From **Power Options** USB selective suspend setting set to **disabled** (didn't fix the issue for me)
- In Android dev options change USB configuration to **MTP** (also didn't fix the issue, as it was automatically switching back to Charging after ~10 attempts to connect)

Fix:

1. Disconnect all USB devices. (very important as disable operation might not be available)
2. Open **System Properties** -> **Device Manager**
3. Disable *USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)*
4. Disable *Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)*
5. Connect your usb devices including android
6. Enable *Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)*
7. Enable *USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)*

[image]

Btw it works fine on windows 7 before it makes updates to motherboard drivers, usually after first updates you can see that usb 3.0 driver support is enabled, and same issue appears.

Hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a random weird solution that worked for me (Windows 8.1, Samsung Galaxy A20, Dell Lattitude laptop).  The A20 uses a USB-C connector which, supposedly, is non-polarized unlike earlier versions of USB.  I flipped the cable over in the phone and the problem went away.  Go figure...  It probably is a mix of MB hardware, drivers, and who knows what else.  Users are on their own as standards evolve.